# Automatically mark all messages as read in Drafts folder

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

I am using the Thunderbird-Extension "Send later" to, well, send some emails later. One annoying thing is that it saves the message in the Drafts folder as an unread message. Does someone have an idea how to change this behavior (except for asking the author of "Send later")?

Spontaneously, I thought of somehow abusing filters to achieve this behavior. The problem here of course is, that one cannot run filters automatically after one *sends* an email but after one *receives* an email.

Of course, I see the option of just right-clicking the "Drafts" folder an then clicking "Mark Folder read" but I think there should be an automatic way to do this.

Comment: Thunderbird always saves draft mails with unread state. This was introduced some versions ago and is very annoying. see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687140

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments I wrote an AutoIt-Script to do the job.

```
AutoItSetOption('WinTitleMatchMode', 2)
$tbWin = 'Mozilla Thunderbird'
WinActivate($tbWin)
$Pos = WinGetPos($tbWin)
MouseClick('left', $Pos[0]+70, $Pos[1]+60, 1, 0)
MouseClick('right', $Pos[0]+70, $Pos[1]+140, 1, 0)
Send('k')
```

It is dependent on my thunderbird configuration and the language setting (beeing english) to work correctly, so don't expect too much ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way, native to Thunderbird, to do this currently.

The only alternative is to have an external function to mark the folder as read periodically or upon a key press.

I would look at AutoHotKey to do tasks like this.

Comment: I really tried to avoid AHK-Hacking ... maybe someone knows an extension for jobs like this?

Comment: I dare say that it would certainly be possible to build an extension to do this but I'm not aware of one and I'm not a Mozilla hacker I'm afraid. AHK almost anyone can do.